# Binary tree with disjoint intervals

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, intervals

I'm trying to create an interval binary tree. It is similar to a regular binary search tree, but nodes are disjoint intervals rather than single numbers. If an interval being inserted has common elements with the already existing intervals, then these intervals are combined into one, and the union of them is inserted. I hope the example below will make it easier to understand.

[image: Interval binary tree example]

Here is the program I have created: https://onecompiler.com/c/3ymwk8zv2

The main part is:

```c
struct node *delete(struct node* root, int key)
{
    if(root == NULL) return root;
    
    if(key < root->low)
        root->left = delete(root->left, key);
    else if(key > root->low)
        root->right = delete(root->right, key);
    else {
        if(root->left == NULL)
            return root->right;
        else if(root->right == NULL)
            return root->left;

        struct node *min = minValue(root->right);
        root->low = min->low;
        root->high = min->high;
        root->id = min->id;

        root->right = delete(root->right, root->low);
    }
    return root;
}

int insertIntersect(struct node *root, int low, int high, int *left, int *right)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;

    insertIntersect(root->left, low, high, left, right);
    insertIntersect(root->right, low, high, left, right);
    
    if(!intersect(root->low, root->high, low, high))
        return 0;
    else 
    {
        *left = min(*left,min(root->low, low));
        *right = max(*right, max(root->high, high));
        root->inter = 1;
        delete(root, root->low);
    }

    return 0;
}

struct node *insert(struct node *root, int low, int high)
{
    if(root == NULL) 
        return createNode(low, high);

    if(low < root->low && high < root->high)
        root->left = insert(root->left, low, high);
    else if (low > root->low && high > root->high)
        root->right = insert(root->right, low, high);
    else
    {
        int left = INT_MAX, right = INT_MIN;
        insertIntersect(root, low, high, &left, &right);
        root->low = left;
        root->high = right;
    }

    return root;
}
```

Executing my code for the above example produces a tree with the following nodes:

- (1-3)
- (8-9)
- (4-25)

even though (8-9) should be incorporated into the (4-25) interval.

I'm looking for help with debugging my solution. I will also appreciate ideas for improving my code.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the solution turned out to be way more complex than I thought initially. There are many things to fix in your code, so I decided to write it from scratch. It's hard to describe everything precisely, so apart from the description, I added code snippets with an implementation in C.

Let each node has the following properties:

- `interval` - with `a` and `b` defining its ends
- `left` - the left subtree's root
- `right` - the right subtree's root

First, we have to define the delete operation as it'll be used when inserting an interval. When deleting we must take into account the fact existing tree nodes can be removed or divided into two parts. It's a bit complex as there are six cases to consider:

1. `root->interval.a < interval.a` and `interval.b < root->interval.b` - `interval` is within `root->interval`. `root` should be split into two nodes with only left and only right child correspondingly. One of these parts is chosen as the new root and the other becomes its second child.
2. `interval.a < root->interval.a` - `interval` contains values lower than the ones in `root`. It makes sense to delete `interval` from the left subtree. If all values in `interval` are lower, there is nothing more to do.
3. `root->interval.b < interval.b` - `interval` contains values higher than the one in `root`. It makes sense to delete `interval` from the right subtree. If all values in `interval` are higher, there is nothing more to do.
4. `interval.a < root->interval.a` and `root->interval.b < interval.b` - `root->interval` is within `interval`. `root` should be deleted. Both children's subtrees are in their final state as previously if needed `interval` was deleted from them. One of the children becomes the new root and the second one is inserted into its subtree.
5. `interval.b` is within `root->interval` - After handling the above cases `interval.a <= root->interval.a`, so the left part of `root->interval` is removed by adjusting `root->interval.a`.
6. `interval.a` is within `root->interval` - After handling the above cases `root->interval.b <= interval.b`, so the right part of `root->interval` is removed by adjusting `root->interval.b`.

```c
Node *delete(Node *root, Interval interval) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (root->interval.a < interval.a && interval.b < root->interval.b) {
        // arbitrary choice of the right part as the new root
        Interval leftRootInterval = { .a = root->interval.a, .b = interval.a };
        Node *leftRoot = createNode(leftRootInterval);
        leftRoot->left = root->left;
        root->interval.a = interval.b;
        root->left = leftRoot;
        return root;
    }

    if (interval.a < root->interval.a) {
        root->left = delete(root->left, interval);
        if (interval.b <= root->interval.a) {
            return root;
        }
    }
    
    if (root->interval.b < interval.b) {
      root->right = delete(root->right, interval);
      if (root->interval.b <= interval.a) {
        return root;       
      }
    }

    if (interval.a < root->interval.a && root->interval.b < interval.b) {
        Node *leftRoot = root->left;
        Node *rightRoot = root->right;
        free(root);
        
        // arbitrary choice of leftRoot as the new root
        if (leftRoot != NULL) {
            root = leftRoot;
            while (leftRoot->right != NULL) {
                leftRoot = leftRoot->right;
            }
            leftRoot->right = rightRoot;
            return root;
        } 

        // there is only the right root
        return rightRoot;
    }
    
    if (root->interval.a < interval.b && interval.b < root->interval.b) {
        root->interval.a = interval.b;
        return root;
    }

    // root->interval.a < interval.a && interval.a < root->interval.b
    root->interval.b = interval.a;
    return root;
}
```

Note the comments in the code above saying the new root is selected arbitrarily. Any of the two nodes could be chosen. Selecting always the same node in those places may lead to unbalance in the tree depending on the sequence of operations. One option to mitigate this issue is to make the choice randomly.

When `interval` is inserted there are four cases to analyze:

1. `interval.b < root->interval.a` - `interval`'s values are lower than `root->interval`'s ones. Insert it to the left subtree.
2. `root->interval.b < interval.a` - `interval`'s values are higher than `root->interval`'s ones. Insert it into the right subtree.
3. `interval.a < root->interval.a` - Because of previously checked case 1 `root->interval.a <= interval.b` - `root->interval` should be extended to the left. Note that some nodes from the left subtree can be absorbed by `root->interval` after the extension. Delete `interval` from the left subtree to remove them. Then check if the remaining part of `root->left->interval` should be also combined with `root->interval`.
4. `root->interval.b < interval.b` - Because of previously checked case 2 `interval.a <= root->interval.b` - `root->interval` should be extended to the right. Note that some nodes from the right subtree can be absorbed by `root->interval` after the extension. Delete `interval` from the right subtree to remove them. Then check if the remaining part of `root->right->interval` should be also combined with `root->interval`.

```c
Node *insert(Node *root, Interval interval) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return createNode(interval);
    }
    
    if (interval.b < root->interval.a) {
      root->left = insert(root->left, interval);
      return root;
    }
    
    if (root->interval.b < interval.a) {
      root->right = insert(root->right, interval);
      return root;
    }
    
    if (interval.a < root->interval.a) {
      root->interval.a = interval.a;
      root->left = delete(root->left, interval);
      Node *leftRoot = root->left;
      if (leftRoot != NULL && root->interval.a == leftRoot->interval.b) {
        root->interval.a = leftRoot->interval.a;
        root->left = leftRoot->left;
        free(leftRoot);
      }
    }
    
    if (root->interval.b < interval.b) {
      root->interval.b = interval.b;
      root->right = delete(root->right, interval);
      Node *rightRoot = root->right;
      if (rightRoot != NULL && root->interval.b == rightRoot->interval.a) {
        root->interval.b = rightRoot->interval.b;
        root->right = rightRoot->right;
        free(rightRoot);
      }
    }

    return root;
}
```

Note that cases 3 and 4 aren't mutually exclusive. `root->interval` can be extended in both directions. Only one end, however, has to be adjusted at a time as the second one if needed is adjusted when handling the other case.